# OpenJDK or Oracle Java on production server

Tags: java

I'm little bit confused about which implementation is better to use on production server? Are there any reason why not pick OpenJDK?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Which version the JDK are you interested in? If it's version 7 and above, then almost all code is shared between Oracle Java and Open JDK.

Check this - [Moving to OpenJDK as the official Java SE 7 Reference Implementation](https://blogs.oracle.com/henrik/entry/moving_to_openjdk_as_the). The OpenJDK is the open-source implementation of the Java SE 7 JSR (JSR 336). Now there is very little difference between the Oracle JDK and the OpenJDK.

Also check this [Q&A](https://blogs.oracle.com/henrik/entry/java_7_questions_answers)

> Q: What is the difference between the source code found in the OpenJDK
> repository, and the code you use to build the Oracle JDK?
>
> A: It is very close - our build process for Oracle JDK releases builds on
> OpenJDK 7 by adding just a couple of pieces, like the deployment code,
> which includes Oracle's implementation of the Java Plugin and Java
> WebStart, as well as some closed source third party components like a
> graphics rasterizer, some open source third party components, like
> Rhino, and a few bits and pieces here and there, like additional
> documentation or third party fonts. Moving forward, our intent is to
> open source all pieces of the Oracle JDK except those that we consider
> commercial features such as JRockit Mission Control (not yet available
> in Oracle JDK), and replace encumbered third party components with
> open source alternatives to achieve closer parity between the code
> bases.OpenJDK 7 above is quite stable. It is the default VM on quite a
> few Linux distros.

However, why do you not want to use Oracle/Sun JRE/JDK?

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I want use JRE version 7. I asked if it matters because there isn't Oracle JRE 7 in my distro packages (Debian). OpenJDK JRE 7 is in testing which I finally don't want to use on my production server anyway. So I end up with building my own package from official Oracle JRE 7 and install it from this package.

Comment: @krocan - I don't understand why you have to build it. You download binaries from Oracle - http://alexander.holbreich.org/2011/11/java-7-on-debian/

Comment: I just followed [Debian wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/JavaPackage). I think it is better to have it included in your packaging tool so you can work with it just like anything else.